# Transimpedance amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

We have current to voltage converter opamp which has below schematic. Below is the formula to find TP1 Voltage :

Vout (TP1) = I1  x R2 or R1 (depend on the switch2 and not calculating the C1)

the question that I have is when the switch1 is open and nothing is connected to opamp V+ should Tp1 Voltage be zero doesn't matter what is the gain resistor(SW2), and if I am correct why I am not getting this in a real scenario.

I think it is because of the noise or rail power but not sure.I am using TP1 (after some other amplifier) for my 4-20mA output calculation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUYmvm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When Vin+ = 0V then Vin- must also = 0V

Vout = I*R  always if not saturated.

When SW1=closed I source drives the output = Vout/Rf so that Vin-input stays at 0V.

For this to work well with high R  values, Op Amp Input bias current Iib = ? must be low.  FET types are very low.

Tp1 voltage = Iib * R   e.g.

for Iib=10nA, R= 100k

- 10nA * 100k= 1mV output.

Comment: So why when I build this circuit and test  Tp1 I am not getting 0V

Comment: does input bias current * R= Vout?

Comment: Yes, could because of feedback capacitor

Comment: Cap leakage R must be >> R1or R2 but this is controlled by \$I_{IB}\$ not cap

Comment: So how do u cancel the input bias current so you will get the same result no matter what gain you have.

Comment: For a true Integrator, you may need a chopper OA or a cap dump reset pulse. or inject an offset null.   What are your design specs?

Comment: @Tony, VR1(2) = I.R but Vout = -I.R :)

Comment: Yes if referred to input current and no if referred to output current such that Iin=0